If Hawking Radiation Leads to Stable Remnants, Why Doesn't Schwinger Pair Production Kick In to Destroy Them?
In the literature on the string theoretical swampland programme, an argument that is often used to support the weak gravity conjecture (that gravity is the weakest force) or the no global symmetries conjecture (that there are no global symmetries in quantum gravity) is about black hole remnants:
If you start with a charged black hole, it will Hawking radiate away its mass, but not its charge (as Hawking radiation is a neutral process), leading to a charged black hole remnant (a charged leftover that has not enough mass to decay any further).
This remnant is problematic because either it is seen as a naked singularity, which violates the (weak) cosmic censorship conjecture that there are no naked singularities, or it violates the covariant entropy bound (that the entropy in a finite volume of space is finite) or more generally black hole thermodynamics. The latter issue is that each remnant would represent a black hole state, and if the charge stems from a continuous gauge group, you have an infinite number of black hole states, which would mean the entropy is infinite.
My question is now: wouldn't such remnants be avoided by Schwinger pair production? The, say, electric field of the charged black hole should produce charged particles, such that the black hole sheds its charge and eventually avoids charged remnants. This would void the remnant argument for the before mentioned conjectures and put them on weaker footing.
Schwinger pair production is the dominant process for $T<m$ with $T$ the Hawking temperature of the black hole and $m$ the black hole mass.

Black hole remnants don't have to be charged, indeed we would expect real black holes to not be significantly charged.
Remnants problematic nature is not due to the charge that they may have, but more about the fact that you would not be able to distinguish between remnants developed by different processes, leading to a different information content (microstate). So you should include all these remnants, and there are a huge number of them, in the quantum calculations, which is supposed to be problematic.
